# How to fetch value in a simpliest way from string

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1

I have two strings:

```
$server = "myhost1"
```

and second - whatever, lets for example:

```
$server_mapping = "myhost1:aaaa,myhost2:bbbb,myhost3:cccc"
```

I need a solution to get mapped string, so if my $server = "myhost1" I would like to get
"aaaa", for "myhost2" - "bbbb".

String with mapping can be separated by ":", or "|" or sth else. Really I dont care. I can create it by my own. But it must me a String. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Start by splitting the second string on the appropriate delimiter:

```
$delim = ','
$pairs = $server_mapping.Split($delim)
```

Find the one that has your reference string and a `:` as a prefix:

```
$target = $pairs.Where({ $_.StartsWith("${server}:") }, 'First')
```

Trim/remove the prefix part:

```
$value = $target.Substring($server.Length + 1)
```

`$value` now holds the string `'aaaa'`, given the sample input.